# Is the Dell T110 using a standard motherboard size?

Tags: motherboard, case, dell-poweredge

I have the opportunity to buy a very cheap, second hand Dell T110 tower. However, I want to move most of the components, namely motherboard, processor and memory, to a rack case.

Is anyone able to work out if the motherboard is a standard size, e.g. mATX, as opposed to a proprietary form factor?

If it is of any help, the owner's manual shows the [screw locations](ftp://ftp.dell.com/Manuals/all-products/esuprt_ser_stor_net/esuprt_poweredge/poweredge-t110-2_Owner%27s%20Manual_en-us.pdf).

Comment: I did, thanks. They have pictures and specs, yes, but not the size of the motherboard. Please reverse your vote down. I can not tell from the pictures if that is what you mean.

Comment: most rack mount cases these days use SSI form factors (SSI EEB, CEB, and MEB). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_form_factor Most do not support ATX-varient form factors, but who knows, you might find one somewhere.

Comment: I have: http://www.scorptec.com.au/product/Cases/Server_&_Rackmount/35673-RM22300

Comment: that case will fit a full ATX motherboard. it doesn't say anything about EATX, or Mini/Micro-ATX though. you should probably contact the manufacturer, or consult the manual.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I also have other cases in mind that state explicitly that they take mATX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is designed for a full ATX motherboard. Saying that, it has been around 2 months since I last opened one up. Here is the specification sheet for you though and may help with any further questions.

http://www.flagshiptech.com/eBay/Dell/T110IITechnical-Guide.pdf